# Calculate new Lat/Lon from initial Lat/Lon plus Cartesian X,Y

Tags: coordinate-system, calculate-values

For small distances (below 10 km), assuming Earth is flat and I have initial Lat0/Lon0 and I have X(km), Y(km) distance From Lat0/Lon0, how can I calculate new Lat/Lon for the added X,Y?

Answer (score 3):

You can't assume that the Earth is flat and provide coordinates in angular units.

But you can assume that the Earth is a sphere and make simple spherical trigonometric calculations.

Define a radius for the sphere, something like `R = 6371 km`. ([Mean radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius#Mean_radius))

Then:

`lambda_1 = lambda_0 + ( X / ( cos( phi_0 ) * R ) )`

`phi_1 = phi_0 + ( Y / R )`

Where: `lambda` is longitude and `phi`is latitude, in radians; `0` and `1` are start and end points.